# Downloading images from csv file to a folder based on its id

Tags: shell-script, wget, images, csv-simple

I have a csv-file that looks like this (short example, there are actually about 20 images per id).

```
2463666;client@email.fi;yleiskuva;7;kivirealty-original;7;http://d372r717gpt3jp.cloudfront.net/itemimages/realty/original/209.15555/img483903555766418535.jpg;pääkuva;1;kivirealty-original;1;http://d372r717gpt3jp.cloudfront.net/itemimages/realty/original/209.15555/img2055776735947406126.jpg;yleiskuva;9;kivirealty-www;9;http://d372r717gpt3jp.cloudfront.net/itemimages/realty/www/209.15555/img7955434706446319955.jpg
2538034;client@email.fi;yleiskuva;8;kivirealty-original;8;http://d372r717gpt3jp.cloudfront.net/itemimages/realty/original/209.15555/img3622394024988955125.jpg;yleiskuva;7;kivirealty-original;7;http://d372r717gpt3jp.cloudfront.net/itemimages/realty/original/209.15555/img7456562650934206782.jpg;yleiskuva;7;kivirealty-thumb;7;http://d372r717gpt3jp.cloudfront.net/itemimages/realty/thumb/209.15555/img3483011994211655969.jpg
...
```

The structure is like this:

id;email;**type_of_image;image_order;image_quality;image_transfer_id;image_url;**

The bold version is repeated as many times as the source xml has these fields, so there can be (most likely is) different amount of images per id. I need to create a folder and download these images in that folder based on the id, for example

```
some_path/2463666/img483903555766418535.jpg
```

There are also image files that are thumbnails and "www-sized", but I only need the ones that have `kivirealty-original` as a field before the image location.

How can I parse the files I need and then `wget` those files to a folder that is named by it's id?

The example file is generated by a shell script, and I would need a code that would do this after that file is done.

Comment: You can parse CSV file with Perl or Python. Since CSV files can have newlines in cell-content, using line oriented tools is a shortcut only beginners try to take. Once you have the cell contents call `wget` or use the language build in retrieval tools.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I'm in a need for bit more detailed examples. I am fairly new to shell scripting. I have been using `awk` to get only the main images to use as preview pictues by looking for value `pääkuva;1;kivirealty-original;1;`, but now I need to download them all (not just pääkuva = main image) and in different folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS=";" read id a remain
do
    while [ "$remain" ]
    do
        IFS=";" read a b test d i_url remain <<< "$remain"
        if [ "$test" == "kivirealty-original" ]
        then
            if [ ! -d "some_path/$id" ]
            then
                mkdir -p "some_path/$id"
            fi
            wget -nd -P "some_path/$id" "$i_url"
        fi
    done
done < file.csv
```

Comment: This did just what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk to create the commands and pipe the output into sh if all works as desired. Here's a code skeleton (you'll have to add the desired wget options)...

```
awk -F\; '
{
    printf "mkdir -p %s/%s\n", "somepath", $1
    for (i=7; i<=NF; i+=5) {
        printf "wget ... %s ... %s/%s ...\n", $i, "somepath", $1
    }
}
' | sh
```